# delimiting each item in arraylist

Tags: java, delimiter

Below is a small extract of my code which is adding a line from an API. There are numerous lines in total.

Each line contains a row of data such as

```
TY8tr,50,34,P,SB,
```

The rows of data are consistent in the type of data. How do i go about splitting each row in the array list by by the ,'s?

```
try {
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();    
    textarea.setText("");

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
       list.add(inputLine);//add r1 to array
       //System.out.println(inputLine); 
    }
    String item = null; 
    String product = null;
    for (int index = 0;index<list.size()-1;index++){
        System.out.println(list.get(index)); 

        textarea.append(index +"\n");
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the input and desired behaviour? There is a String.split method.

Comment: the input line is TY8tr,50,34,P,SB. The desired output is to be able to split the commas within each row.

Comment: i want to then be able to search any row for the delimited items

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the `String.split` method ([docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))).

```
String[] strs = inputLine.split(",");
```

Looping through the split values:

```
String[] strs = null;

for (String line : list)
{
    strs = line.split(",");

    for (String column : strs)
    {
         // do something with the columns, e.g.:
         if (column.equals(searchVal))
             // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: i wish to keep this as an arraylist, how do i perform a split on each item of the arraylist?

Comment: This doesnt bring back the entire row when i search for TY8tr

Comment: This only seems to bring back TY8tr but it doesnt bring back 50 34 P SB

Comment: String[] strs = null;

    for (Iterator it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        String line = (String) it.next();
        strs = line.split(",");
      for (String column : strs){
       // {
          
          if (column.equals("TY8tr"))
            // do something with the columns, e.g.:
      System.out.println(column);  
         
      }